# Send https post request

Tags: https, http-post

I can able to send http post request. I used chrome's SimpleRestClient extension to send following http post request

```
http://localhost:8161/api/message/QueueTest?type=queue&body=message
```

Now I want to do https(http secure) post request, I try to do the following link but I can't. How can I send?

```
https://localhost:8161/api/message/QueueTest?type=queue&body=message
```

Comment: Is SSL configured on the web server? If so it won't be on the same port as HTTP ...

Comment: i guess this is `get` request not `post`?

Comment: What type of web server you are using?

Comment: am using activemq JMS server

Comment: It might seem to be `get` request but I checkout `post` in `SimpleRestClient` extension